# Algorithm question

Tags: algorithm

If f(x) = O(g(x)) as x -> infinity, then

A. g is the upper bound of f

B. f is the upper bound of g.

C. g is the lower bound of f.

D. f is the lower bound of g.

Can someone please tell me when they think it is and why?

Comment: Have you looked at something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation?  It gives definitions for what this notation means.

Comment: Folks, I'm considering Big O notation as on the fence enough to be on topic, since it is used in so many answers here. You're free to disagree with me, but I'm not closing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

> g is the upper bound of f

When x goes towards infinity, worst case scenario is `O(g(x))`. That means actual exec time can be lower than `g(x)`, but never worse than `g(x)`.

**EDIT:**

As Oli Charlesworth pointed out, that is only true with arbitrary constant k <= 1 and not in general. [Please look at his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842611/algorithm-question/5842968#5842968) for the general case.

Comment: @oli: k represents what? constants?

Comment: @user: Unfortunately, it's not!  "*`k.g` is the upper bound of `f`*" would be correct.

Comment: @usoban: Yes, an arbitrary constant.

Comment: if we're that strict, it's k*g(x)+a :)

Comment: @usoban: There's no additive constant.

Comment: Why? Not trying to argue, but when talking in big-o notation, constants are skipped anyway. When talking about actual time, they are important, of course.
I'll admit, my experience in this field is not so wide, so I'd like to see your answer :)

Comment: @usoban: Because the definition of Big-O is that `|f(n)| <= k|g(n)|` for all `n > n0`, where `n0` and `k` are constants to be found.  Your answer assumes that `k=1`.

Comment: Looked it up, and you're right. I'll update the answer and point to yours.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is that none of these is correct.

The definition of [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-o_notation#Formal_definition) is that:

```
|f(x)| <= k|g(x)|
```

for all `x > x0`, for some `x0` and `k`.

In specific cases, `|k|` might be less than or equal to 1, in which case it would be correct to say that "|g| is the upper bound of |f|".  But in general, that's not true.

Comment: Shouldn't the last paragraph have "|g| is an upper bound of f"? With the definition you have, x is O(-x^2).

Answer (score 0):

The question checks your understanding of the basics of asymptotic algebra, or big-oh notation. In

> `f(x) = O(g(x))` as `x` approaches infinity

the question says that when you feed the function `f` a value `x`, the value which `f` computes from `x` is then *in the order* of that returned from another function, `g(x)`. As an example, suppose

```
f(x) = 2x
g(x) = x
```

then the value `g(x)` returns when fed `x` is of the same order as that `f(x)` returns for `x`. Specifically, the two functions return a value that is in the order of `x`; the functions are both *linear*. It doesn't matter whether `f(x)` is `2x` or `½x`; for any constant factor at all `f(x)` will return a value that is in the order of `x`. This is because big-oh notation is about ignoring constant factors. Constant factors don't grow as `x` grows and so we assume they don't matter nearly as much as `x` does.

We restrict `g(x)` to a specific set of functions. `g(x)` can be `x`, or `ln(x)`, or `log(x)` and [so on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) and [so forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities). It may look as if when

```
f(x) = 2x
g(x) = x
```

`f(x)` yields values higher than `g(x)` and therefore is the upper bound of `g(x)`. But once again, we ignore the constant factor, and we say that the *order-of* upper bound, which is what big-oh is all about, is that of `g(x)`.